# inarray function won't work with session variable that is set to array

Tags: php, arrays

Everytime the script that contains the inarray function executes, the element disappears and the ones that comes after it. I believe it means that it's not working. I set the session variable to an array just like setting a regular variable to an array.

```
$items = array("A", "B", "C");
$_SESSION["item"] = $items;

if(inarray("A", $_SESSION["item"])) { echo "An item!"; }
```

This doesn't work. I can't get the echo to work. On top of that, the elements that comes after it disappears indicating that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean standard [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function then there is the mistake in your code